# issues deploying a JAVA application to weblogic 11g

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, deployment, weblogic

I have a simple JSP/Servlets application. The app is already deployed to the server and is running at say URL **http://www.servername:7001/myapp1/jsp/login.jsp**. I have made some substantial changes to the code and I redeployed it as **myapp2** in the server. However if I try to access it at this URL,,say **http://www.servername:7001/myapp2/jsp/login.jsp**, this gives me a "resource not found error". Is the URL mapped to the application somewhere? What do I need to do to access the newly deployed project. I do not want to remove the old project  till I am sure the new one works properly

Comment: What does the server log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify a context root. There are a couple of places this might appear.

1) Inside your EAR file in META-INF/application.xml, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
  id="Application_ID" version="5">
  <display-name>myapp2</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myapp2.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/myapp2</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

2) In the WAR file, in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.2</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>myapp2</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```